# How can i style date that dynamicaly reading from database?

Tags: database, date, css

dynamical reading date from database in codeigniter like given below

```
<?php echo format_date($row['date'], 'd M')?>
```

and the result will disply like `27 Jul`

I want to style it to like this image http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/date-icon/16.jpg

How can i style like this image please help..

Comment: With some neat CSS 3 tricks and some effort. That's how I would do it...Otherwise, show us what you've tried to style it with and I'll give you a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

I’m afraid it can’t be done with CSS alone. The main problem is that the components of the date do not appear as elements in the markup, so you cannot style them differently from each other, except to a limited degree. By setting a width that forces them to different lines, you get the opportunity to use `:first-line`. But the possibilities of styling that pseudoelement are rather limited, by the specs and in practice.

So you would need to modify the generating code to produce something like

```
<span class=date><span class=day>27</span><span class=month>Jul</span></span>
```

Then you can e.g. style such an element as an inline block and the inner `span` elements as blocks and set background and content colors, font properties, and rounded border for the outer element.

Comment: So... in short: use CSS to style it. ;)

Comment: guys i wan to style like this "http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/date-icon/16.jpg" watch it after give a solution

Comment: @user1514316, repeating the image does not help. Please explain which part of my answer you did not understand. And don’t expect others to do the coding for you. As soon as you have set up markup that can be used for styling, the solution is almost trivial; but you can ask for help with specific issues after you have tried to do it yourself.

Comment: Agreed, CSS is not enough, you'll need some extra markup. However, it seems like OP is just waiting for someone to write his CSS for him.

Comment: i find it..we could do it with css...:)

Comment: @user1514316, what is the point of that “i find it” remark? Please accept the best answer or explain what is wrong with it. If you think you have found a better answer yourself, please post it for analysis and for the benefit of others who might have the same problem.